# Lipschitz-continuity of matrix-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-calculus, lipschitz-functions

I would like to show the Lipschitz-continuity of a matrix-valued function $\sigma$.
Suppose $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}, \beta\mapsto \sqrt{\phi(\lVert \beta \rVert_2)}I_{d\times d} $ where the function
$$ \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, z\mapsto \sqrt{\phi(z)} $$
is Lipschitz-continuous.
I would like to show Lipschitz-continuity in the respective $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$-norms. But for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we have
$$
\lVert \sigma(x)-\sigma(y) \rVert_2 =  \max\{|\lambda| : \lambda \mathrm{~eigenvalue~of~} (\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)(\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)^T\} = \sqrt{ | \phi(\lVert x \rVert_2) - \phi(\lVert y \rVert_2)|}.
$$

I don't see, how the Lipschitz-continuity of $\sqrt{\phi(z)}$ is helping me, but the author seems to use it to conclude the L-cont. of $\sigma$. Could someone explain? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Lipschitz-continuity of $\sqrt{\phi}$ there is some $L>0$ with $$|\sqrt{\phi(s)}-\sqrt{\phi(t)}|\leq L|s-t|$$ for all $s,t\in\Bbb R$. Hence we get for $x,y\in\Bbb R^d$ by the reverse triangle inequality: $$\|\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)\|=|\sqrt{\phi(\|x\|_2)}-\sqrt{\phi(\|y\|_2)}|\leq L\big|\|x\|_2-\|y\|_2\big|\leq L\|x-y\|$$
Hence $\sigma$ is Lipschitz-continuous. (Basically the composition of Lipschitz-continuous functions is again Lipschitz-continuous, here we have the functions $\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R,x\mapsto\|x\|$, $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,r\mapsto\sqrt{\phi(r)}$ and $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^{d\times d},s\mapsto sI$.)

Comment: By the Lipschitz-continuity of $\sqrt{\phi}$ we have $|\sqrt{\phi(s)}-\sqrt{\phi(t)}| \le L|t-s|$, right? But we have $\sqrt{|\phi(s)-\phi(t)|} \ge |\sqrt{\phi(s)}-\sqrt{\phi(t)}|$ ?

Comment: Ah nevermind, the matrix-2-norm was wrong. We do get $\lVert \sigma(x)-\sigma(y) \lVert_2 = |\sqrt{\phi(x)}-\sqrt{\phi(y)}|$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I edited the post.